# Definition of Ordinal (w/ Axiom of Regularity) (problem 37, page 208, Enderton's Elements of Set Theory)

Tags: set-theory, alternative-proof

Given the definition of an ordinal to be well-ordered by $\in$ and transitive, I am interested with proving the following:

[image]

I know and understand the following which easily proves it, but uses the Axiom of Choice:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Is there a proof that uses ZF axioms and not the Axiom of Choice?

[sorry for posting pictures, but I rather typeset in a LaTeX editor with macros + \newcommands]

Comment: You seem to be missing a definition of "ordinal". It's not uncommon for your proposition to _be_ the definition of ordinal, in the presence of Regularity.

Comment: I edited my post to include what I found to be the most common definition. I must ask however, for the proposition to be the definition of ordinal must one assume the axiom of choice as well as regularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is totally ordered by $\in$. We must prove that $X$ is *well* ordered by $\in$.

Therefore assume that $A\subseteq X$ is non-empty. We seek to prove that $A$ has an $\in$-least element.

Simply apply the Axiom of Regularity to $A$! This gives $a\in A$ such that $a\cap A=\varnothing$. However, then $a$ must be a $\in$-minimal element of $A$, because what that means is exactly that there is no $b\in A$ with $b\in a$, or in other words that $a\cap A=\varnothing$. Because $X$ is *totally* ordered by $\in$, a minimal element is necessarily a *least* element, as required.